# Is it possible to change the "fooevents" ticketID format?

Tags: woocommerce

We setup an woocommerce webshop with fooevents to be able to sell tickets with an barcode. We query the db of the webshop via a script which is called by a cronjob. This script fetches all sold ticket and pushes them into another system via an API. Unfortunately the other system requires an specific barcode format:

`| 1 digit prefix | 3 digit system id | 2 digit device id | 7 digit unique ticket id |`

We hoped we could define the ticket format in foo events via the admin interface but I cant find such option (also not with help of Google) The in total "6 digit prefix" is always the same so could be hard coded. I tried to find the place where the ticket id is generated but I was also not able to find that line of code.

Can someone help me out an explain me how i can achieve this is the most easy way?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the barcode layout via the admin interface. The ticketID (used for the barcode) is generated in the class `fooevents/classes/woohelper.php`

```
...
1254 |   $post['ID'] = wp_insert_post( $post );
1255 |   $ticketID = $post['ID'].$rand;                   <- the ticketID / barcode
1256 |   $post['post_title'] = '#'.$ticketID;
1257 |   $postID = wp_update_post( $post );
...
```